# How to guess the encoding of a file with no BOM in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using the StreamReader class in .NET like this:

```
using( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( "c:\somefile.html", true ) {
    string filetext = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This works fine when the file has a BOM.  I ran into trouble with a file with no BOM .. basically I got gibberish.  When I specified Encoding.Unicode it worked fine, eg:

```
using( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( "c:\somefile.html", Encoding.Unicode, false ) {
    string filetext = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

So, I need to get the file contents into a string.  So how do people usually handle this?  I know there's no solution that will work 100% of the time, but I'd like to improve my odds .. there is obviously software out there that tries to guess (eg, notepad, browsers, etc).  Is there a method in the .NET framework that will guess for me?  Does anyone have some code they'd like to share?

More background: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373081/how-can-i-best-guess-the-encoding-when-the-bom-byte-order-mark-is-missing) is pretty much the same as mine, but I'm in .NET land.  That question led me to a blog listing various [encoding detection](http://fredeaker.blogspot.com/2007/01/character-encoding-detection.html) libraries, but none are in .NET

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Libary**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx

[**And perhaps a useful thread on stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661717/c-cycle-through-encodings/673308#673308)

Comment: The code project library looks pretty good.  It wraps the Microsoft "MLang" api, which is maybe gross, but it appears that is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

You should read this article by Raymond Chen.  He goes into detail on how programs can guess what an encoding is (and some of the fun that comes from guessing).

*[Some files come up strange in Notepad](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093)*

Answer (score 1):

I had good luck with [**Ude**](http://code.google.com/p/ude/), a `C#` port of `Mozilla Universal Charset Detector`.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is designed in a way that it is unlikely to have a text encoded in an arbitrary 8bit-encoding like latin1 being decoded to proper unicode using UTF-8.

So the minimum approach is this (pseudocode, I don't talk .NET):

try:
   u = some_text.decode("UTF-8")
except UnicodeDecodeError:
   u = some_text.decode("most-likely-encoding")

For the most-likely-encoding one usually uses e.g. latin1 or cp1252 or whatever. More sophisticated approaches might try & find language-specific character pairings, but I'm not aware of something that does that as a library or some such.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to do something similar a while back:

http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Localization/NCharDet/

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32's IsTextUnicode.

In the general sense, it is a difficult promlem. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky technique might be to take an MD5 of the text, then decode the text and re-encode it in various encodings, MD5'ing each one. If one matches you guess it's that encoding.

That's obviously too slow for something that handles a lot of files but for something like a text editor I could see it working.

Other than that, it'll be hands dirty porting the java libraries from [this post](http://fredeaker.blogspot.com/2007/01/character-encoding-detection.html) that came from the Delphi SO question, or using the IE MLang feature.

Answer (score 0):

See my (recent) answer to this (as far as I can tell, equivalent) question: [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file/5830273#5830273)

It does NOT attempt to guess across a range of possible "national" encodings like MLang and NCharDet do, but rather assumes you know what kind of non-unicode files you're likely to encounter. As far as I can tell from your question, it should address your problem pretty reliably (without relying on the "black box" of MLang).