# How do I transform an ascii byte vector into a string?

Tags: c#, string, arrays

Given a byte array (byte[]) is there any quick (as in short and aesthetic) way of transforming this into a string och character array? Assume that the bytes in the array is text represented in ascii.

I'm working in c# right now, and can't find any obvious methods to use. But I'm also interested in a general solution applicable to any modern programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString will return a string from the given byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Important note: as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700061/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string) - Strings are Unicode, so **you must specify an encoding on conversion**.

`System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` is one option, but make sure that the byte array contains only ASCII encoded characters.